# Loaded Voltage Divider

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-divider

Could I get some help with this question:

Set up an equation for the I (V) containing constants E, R1 and R2 and
variable U, when the voltage in M1 is loaded. RL shall not be included in the expression.

[image]

M1

Comment: If the value of U is fixed, it's not really operating as a voltage divider. You can analyze this simply with Ohm's law and KCL, think of U as a voltage source.

Comment: I'm thinking of using the voltage divider formula, however I think I need to apply something more to get the the formula I(V) right...

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont get the question.  What is I(V) and where is M1 ?  Are you looking for I as a function of v, where V is U?  Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear. I(V) is I as a function of the voltage U. M1 is the whole circuit, just a name on the circuit. So yes, I am trying to find I as a function of U. :) I've been stuck with this problem for three days now, and I really don't know how to find the function

Answer (score 1):

Break the circuit at AB, and obtain the Thevenin equivalent, consisting of Vth as the divider E with R1 and R2 and Rth as the parallel combination of R1 and R2. With this,
now you can solve for U as the divider of Vth, and Rth and RL..
If it is I you are solving for, then you know U, Vth, and the resistance between them to use ohms law to calculate I.
[image]

Comment: When you say Vth as the divider E with R1 and R2, I think of putting it like E * R2/R1+R2, and Rth as R1*R2/R1+R2. However I don't really understand how I can make an equation of this to find I over U, I(U)

Comment: Yes, that's right.  If you then redraw the circuit (unfortunately, i don't know how to show it in the comments, and i'm nit sure if I'm supposed to provide a new answer...), you might  see how to calculate I.  The problem stament  defines U as the voltage across Rl. ....see my previous answer, i'll redraw the Thevenin eq circuit there..maybe that will help  you see  it....

Comment: well I have I picture like that, excatly like that. To calculate I, I need to set Vth/Rth...am I right? If my E=2V, R1=330 and R2=470 is that in the first place then Vth should be 2*470/330+470 and Rth should be 330*470/330+470..Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite, think about the voltage across Rth in the diagram.

Comment: From the beginning R1 = 330 and R2 = 470 and E=2V

Comment: This was a tricky one, because I now have the voltage Vth and the resistance Rth..the only way for me to calculate I is through ohms law..but that doesn't seem to be right

Comment: No, you are right....you're just not seeing it... You have (vth- u) across Rth.  That is all you need to solve for I via Ohm's law (because the problem stated that it be given in terms of U rather than RL)

Comment: Great, glad i could help